# Register an ole server exe during wix installion

Tags: wix, installation, wix3.7

```
<CustomAction Id="RegisterEXE"
                Directory="INSTALLDIR"
                  ExeCommand="&quot;[INSTALLDIR]MyApp.exe&quot; /Register"
                  Execute="immediate"
                  Return="ignore"                  
                 />

 <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action='RegisterEXE' After='InstallFinalize' />
 </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The exe should be registered as ole server.
but it does not register.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `CustomAction` Attibute `Impersonate` has default value of `yes`. You need to set it to no to run the executable with Elevated permission (The permission which installer have now). OLE Server registration requires changes in HKCU and HKLM.

Read Wix [doc](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/customaction.html)

```
<CustomAction Id="RegisterEXE"
                  Directory="INSTALLDIR"
                  ExeCommand="&quot;[INSTALLDIR]TKW5.exe&quot; /Register"
                  Execute="deferred"
                  Return="ignore"  
                  Impersonate="no"
                 />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action='RegisterEXE' After='InstallFiles' />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: This is not the proper way to do it.

Comment: Besides *`This is not the proper way to do it`* as @ChristopherPainter already mentioned, it's exactly that kind of ***`use this` answer*** that doesn't teach you anything. I find, you should **really add some words** about `Execute="deferred"` and `Impersonate="no"`.

Comment: To prevent misunderstandings: the solution you gave ***may*** help in some circumstances, so my downvote addresses only the *use this* aspect: Especially when you do something that is strongly discouraged, you should **know what you are doing** and so wisely decide if the benefit will outperform the cost.

Answer (score 3):

Per [Windows Installer Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204770%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Do not use the SelfReg and TypeLib tables.
>
> •Installation package authors are strongly advised against using self registration and the
>   SelfReg table. Instead they should register modules by authoring one
>   or more of the tables in the Registry Tables Group. Many of the
>   benefits of the Windows Installer are lost with self registration
>   because self-registration routines tend to hide critical configuration
>   information. For a list of the reasons for avoiding self registration
>   see SelfReg table.
>
> •Installation package authors are strongly advised
>   against using the TypeLib table. Instead of using the TypeLib table,
>   register type libraries by using Registry table. If an installation
>   using the TypeLib table fails and must be rolled back, the rollback
>   may not restore the computer to the same state that existed prior to
>   the rollback.

The reason is that self registration is an out of process execution that is slower, prone to failure and untrackable by the Windows Installer.  This creates problems for resilency, rollback, uninstall and upgrade scenarios.   The better approach is to "harvest" the COM metadata from the EXE and author it natively into the MSI.  This way MSI simply copies the files and applies the registry entries.  In the event of a rollback, MSI knows what it did and simply reverts it.  For more information see:

[Reasons for Avoiding Self Registration](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/resons-avoiding-self-registration)

The way to achieve this in WiX is to run the EXE through [Harvest Tool (Heat)](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html).  This will generate a .WxS fragment that you can then include in your installer.

Comment: It is rare, but self-registration can also be used to write values into the registry that has nothing to do with self-registration at all. These are poorly written COM/DCOM servers that may even hack security settings. Extracting the registry information and writing with the MSI installer makes this transparent to whoever inspects the MSI.

Comment: Kind of funny that the Symantec list is lifted from the Windows Installer Team blog, Rule 19 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2006/05/12/595950.aspx

Comment: I think he is using a custom registration process from his own exe. He may be doing something more than you and me can expect using custom registration.

Comment: *`The better approach is to`* and the following -- I'd stress this (typographically?), maybe also rephrase ("better approach" seems a bit weak) because it's actually your answer, isn't it? I find the things *not to do* are too dominant, which is psychologically bad ;)

Comment: I only have the patience to do things the right way. I don't have time for PC.  Your welcome to edit the answer if you'd like.

Comment: BTW another consideration is RegFree COM and eliminating COM all together. It is 2016... :)